# Razor Pages Custom Page Routing

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, routes, razor-pages

This question has been asked earlier and as I am new to `Razor Pages`, unable to figure out how I can make the required (Silly one). So here it's: I've a `razor page` where I show a list of data where I've to make the page routing or url as follows:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Data)
{
  <a href="./search_details/id/@item.Id">@item.Name @item.City @item.State</a>
}
```

So pretty simple, so in the `Startup.cs`, I tried to do the following to make it work. Unfortunately failed:

```
//This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
    {
        // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
        options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
        options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
    });

    services.AddMvc();
    services.AddEntityFrameworkSqlite().AddDbContext<MyDbContext>();
    services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
    services.AddMvc().AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
    {
        //Here is the configured routing that I tried
        options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/search_details", "/search_details/id");
    });
}
```

I would like to return the url as **./search_details/id/1002** and in the back-end, did this to get the query string value:

```
string id = this.RouteData.Values["id"].ToString();
```

This is pretty basic, but as I said failed (**Failed** means in the back-end, the query string doesn't hit while debugging). I've one more scenario and this thing is bothering me right now the most. My requirement is to hide the page name as well. Something like this:

```
localhost:8080/search_details/id/1002
```

To

```
localhost:8080/1002
```

Is there appropriate way where I can accomplish that? I understand that's a bad practice for other purposes but for the time being, I would go with it.

**N.B**: I am not willing to do it in the client-end unless there is no alternate. If possible, better with something server-side using `C#`.

Comment: Nothing to do with your issue, which has been answered, but you are calling `AddMvc` three times. There is no need to do that. You can chain the `SetCompatibilityVersion` and `AddRazorPagesOptions` to the first call to `AddMvc`: `services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(...).AddRazorPagesOptions(...)`

Comment: OK @Mike Brind. Thanks to notify that and will do it in a single statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Route Templates in Razor pages :

https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/routing

Comment out this line `options.Conventions.AddPageRoute` , and in your `search_details` page add nullable parameter :

```
@page "{id?}"
```

In cs file , you can get route data like :

```
public void OnGet(string id)
{

}
```

For the second requirement, you can add template like :

```
options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/search_details", "{id}");
```

So that `localhost:8080/1002` will redirect to `search_details` page and you will get `id` as route data also .

Comment: If you can see this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57858067/custom-404-page-doesnt-get-redirected @Nan Yu.