# Custom 404 Page Doesn't Get Redirected

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I am trying to redirect to 404 custom error page whenever a user types wrong url in the browser. Say a user types **https://localhost:44332/foo** (foo page doesn't exist), then it should redirect to the custom error page. In my case, it doesn't, but for this, it works:

```
https://localhost:44332/foo/foo-page
```

This get redirected to custom error page. I did a small workout in my project and believe, this causes an issue for this redirection - **https://localhost:44332/foo**.

I've a page, say `user-details` which redirects with a query string something like this:

```
https://localhost:44332/user-details?=1002
```

So in the `Startup.cs` file, I did this to make the url user-friendly:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
    {
        // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
        options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
        options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
    });

    services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2).AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
    {
        //Here is the routing done
        options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/user-details", "{id}");
    });

    services.AddEntityFrameworkSqlite().AddDbContext<MyDbContext>();
}
```

So what the above code does, when a user types **https://localhost:4433/1002**, it gets the related details redirecting to user details page (**Note**: I omitted the user-details page name from the url that works fine). So now whenever I type a wrong page name that doesn't exist, say foo or whatever (**https://localhost:44332/foo**), instead of redirecting to error page, gets redirected to the `user-details` page. Anything that I missed or required to do to make it work accordingly?

**N.B**: Handling errors in the `Startup.cs` file as follows

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
   if (env.IsDevelopment())
   {
      app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
   }
   else
   {
      //Error handling here
      app.UseStatusCodePages();
      app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");

      //The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
      app.UseHsts();
    }

  app.UseMvc();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is:

```
options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/user-details", "{id}");
```

Just because it's named `id` doesn't mean that it's going to somehow only take ints. You've essentially created a route that will catch anything without an additional route segment: i.e. `/foo` will catch, but `/foo/bar` won't. You can add a constraint to help, i.e `"{id:int}"`, which will then only catch if the route segment can be converted to an int.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Chris Pratt. But I've one more thing. For int part, it could be done but what if I've unique names that could be used as url, say `user-details/jack` or say `user-details/jack-2`? Is there a way that I can distinguish?

Comment: Nope. In that case, any possible string could be passed in the URL. However, if nothing matches in the database, you should be manually returning a 404 from the action.